# Unable to set datasource of datagridview from List

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, datasource

I have a datagridview that's getting its data from Access via `OleDbDataReader`.

The problem is as follows
Reading data into Data table then setting `datasource = dt` => works

```
dt.Load(dr);
```

taking the dt and applying Linq to it => empty GridView

```
GVMultiple.DataSource = (from myRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
                         where myRow.Field<string>("State") == "Succeeded"
                         select myRow)
```

making the `Linq.ToList()` => shows columns with names "RowError","RowState","Table" and "hasErrors" which aren't my columns

```
GVMultiple.DataSource = (from myRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
                         where myRow.Field<string>("State") == "Succeeded"
                         select myRow).ToList()
```

Reading data into `Object` of a custom `List then` setting `datasource  = List` => empty `GridView`

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    UserList.Add(new UserInfo()
    {
        ID = (int)dr["ID"],
        UserName = (string)dr["User Name"]
    });
}

GVMultiple.DataSource = UserList
```

Can someone tell me what is going on?

Comment: `ID` and `UserName` are properties or Fields?

Comment: The are defined as follows:
class UserInfo
    {
        public int ID;
        public string UserName;
        etc..
    }

Answer (score 1):

In order to make `DataBinding` work you've to use `Properties`. `Fields` doesn't support `DataBinding`.

Modify your class as below to make it work.

```
class UserInfo 
{ 
    public int ID {get;set;}  //convert fields to property
    public string UserName{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved one of the problems. 
What about the other part where I am unable to filter my dt using LINQ and setting the datasource to that.

Comment: Don't use linq. Just set `DataTable` as datasource and use [Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.defaultview.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

> GVMultiple.DataSource = (from myRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
>                            where myRow.Field("State") == "Succeeded"
>                            select myRow)
>
> making the Linq.ToList() => shows columns with names "RowError","RowState","Table" and "hasErrors" which aren't my columns

RowError","RowState","Table" and "hasErrors" are properties of the DataRow - which is what is in the list you created.

Take a look into the .CopyToDataTable() extension method.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx

```
    GVMultiple.DataSource = (from myRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
                     where myRow.Field<string>("State") == "Succeeded"
                     select myRow).CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is that the data grid view is not able to recognize the collection of new data as accepted format for display.

When using Linq queries to filter the data and re display it in data grid view you must always return the query result to any data source as data view.

> DataView constructs an index, which significantly increases the
>   performance of operations that can use the index, such as filtering
>   and sorting. The index for a DataView is built both when the DataView
>   is created and when any of the sorting or filtering information is
>   modified. Creating a DataView and then setting the sorting or
>   filtering information later causes the index to be built at least
>   twice: once when the DataView is created, and again when any of the
>   sort or filter properties are modified.

For example:

```
DataTable dt = empData.loadEmployee();
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(c => c.Field<string>("First Name").ToLower()
    .Contains(txtSearch.Text.ToLower())).AsDataView();

dgvEmpManag.DataSource = bs;
```

In the example I am looking for employee with first name like the search term in the text box `txtSearch` when found the data grid view will display filtered results of my search `AsDataView()`.